# problems with stack in NASM

Tags: assembly, stack, nasm

I'm writing a program in NASM that calculates a Fibonacci sequence and prints it. It takes user input for two seed values and the number of iterations, stores them on the stack, and then calls a 'fib' subroutine to do the calculations and printing. I'm using a library from [here](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/index.php) in order to do things such as read input/print things.

Here is my asm_main:

```
asm_main:
        enter   0,0                 ; setup routine
        pusha

    mov eax, prompt1        ; access first prompt
    call    print_string        ; print prompt
    call    read_int        ; read input and stores in eax
    push    eax         ; store input on stack

    mov eax, prompt2        ; access second prompt
    call    print_string        ; print prompt
    call    read_int        ; read input and stores in eax
    push    eax         ; store input on stack

    mov eax, prompt3        ; access third prompt
    call    print_string        ; print prompt
    call    read_int        ; read input and stores in eax
    push    eax         ; store input on stack

    call    fib         ; call fib subroutine to calculate sequence
    call    print_nl        ; end with a newline
```

and here is the fib subroutine:

```
fib:
    pop ecx         ; retrieve number of iterations from stack
    pop ebx         ; retrieve second seed value from stack
    pop eax         ; retrieve first seed value from stack

    _looper:            ; section to be looped
        mov edx, eax
        add edx, ebx    ; sum = a + b
        call    print_int
        call    print_nl
        mov eax, ebx    ; a = b
        mov ebx, edx    ; b = sum
        loop _looper
    ret
```

However, this pushing and popping is not working correctly and I can't figure out why. When I enter "3" as the first seed value, "5" as the second seed value, and "7" for the number of iterations, here is the result of a register dump called within fib:

```
Register Dump # 1
EAX = 00000005 EBX = 00000007 ECX = 080484D4 EDX = BF97A1B4
ESI = 00000000 EDI = 00000000 EBP = BF97A168 ESP = BF97A144
EIP = 08048480 FLAGS = 200282       SF
```

am I missing something here? As per my understanding the stack should be last-in/first-out, and I cannot figure out what is going wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `call fib` then inside `fib` the first thing you'll be popping off the stack is the return address. Popping that off is fine as long as you make sure you push it back on after you popped off the arguments otherwise the `ret` instruction at the end is going to send you somewhere you did not intend.

You might for example do

```
fib:
    pop edx         ; pop return address
    pop ecx         ; retrieve number of iterations from stack
    pop ebx         ; retrieve second seed value from stack
    pop eax         ; retrieve first seed value from stack
    push edx        ; put return address back on stack
    ...
```

But a more conventional approach is to set up a stack frame with

```
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
```

then access the arguments with

```
    mov ecx, [ebp+8]
    mov ebx, [ebp+12]
```

and so on

and then pop off the stack frame and the arguments at the end:

```
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 12
```

This latter approach allows you to access the arguments when needed - not just on entry to the routine.